# Convert points from image to UIImageView points, contentMode-aware

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

Let's say I have an image (e.g. 1024 x 768 px) which is displayed in a UIImageView (e.g. 300 x 300 px).
Now, I'd like to convert a point from the image, e.g. the position of a person's nose (x: 500, y:600), to the corresponding point on the UIImageView with its contentMode taken into account.

If the contentMode is fixed at UIViewContentModeScaleToFill, conversion will be easy. But if it's UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit, things getting more complex.

Is there an elegant way to achieve that? I don't really want to calculate that for every single contentMode (more than 10, I think).

Thanks!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Today, I've had some spare time to put together my solution to this problem and publish it on GitHub: [UIImageView-GeometryConversion](https://github.com/nubbel/UIImageView-GeometryConversion)

It's a category on UIImageView that provides methods for converting points and rects from the image to view coordinates and respects all of the 13 different content modes.

Hope you like it!

Comment: Very nice - It would be even nicer if you had also provided the other way around (from imageView coordinate to image coordinate).

Comment: Dont bother, I have done it for some of the modes, I am finishing it right now and will send you a pull request on github later today.

Comment: I have posted a pull request: https://github.com/nubbel/UIImageView-GeometryConversion/pull/1

Comment: Thank you, I merged your changes!

Comment: Facing Rotation Problem using camera image the library convert in different then presented image.

Comment: I've just noticed a bug in the Swift version. Lines 139 and 140 should be `let imageTopLeft = convertPoint(fromViewPoint: viewTopLeft)` and `let imageBottomRight = convertPoint(fromViewPoint: viewBottomRight)` respectively.

Answer (score 10):

That's my quick'n'dirty solution:

```
- (CGPoint)convertPoint:(CGPoint)sourcePoint fromContentSize:(CGSize)sourceSize {
    CGPoint targetPoint = sourcePoint;
    CGSize  targetSize  = self.bounds.size;

    CGFloat ratioX = targetSize.width / sourceSize.width;
    CGFloat ratioY = targetSize.height / sourceSize.height;

    if (self.contentMode == UIViewContentModeScaleToFill) {
        targetPoint.x *= ratioX;
        targetPoint.y *= ratioY;
    }
    else if(self.contentMode == UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit) {
        CGFloat scale = MIN(ratioX, ratioY);

        targetPoint.x *= scale;
        targetPoint.y *= scale;

        targetPoint.x += (self.frame.size.width - sourceSize.width * scale) / 2.0f;
        targetPoint.y += (self.frame.size.height - sourceSize.height * scale) / 2.0f;
    }
    else if(self.contentMode == UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill) {
        CGFloat scale = MAX(ratioX, ratioY);

        targetPoint.x *= scale;
        targetPoint.y *= scale;

        targetPoint.x += (self.frame.size.width - sourceSize.width * scale) / 2.0f;
        targetPoint.y += (self.frame.size.height - sourceSize.height * scale) / 2.0f;
    }

    return targetPoint;
}

- (CGRect)convertRect:(CGRect)sourceRect fromContentSize:(CGSize)sourceSize {
    CGRect targetRect = sourceRect;
    CGSize targetSize  = self.bounds.size;

    CGFloat ratioX = targetSize.width / sourceSize.width;
    CGFloat ratioY = targetSize.height / sourceSize.height;

    if (self.contentMode == UIViewContentModeScaleToFill) {
        targetRect.origin.x *= ratioX;
        targetRect.origin.y *= ratioY;

        targetRect.size.width *= ratioX;
        targetRect.size.height *= ratioY;
    }
    else if(self.contentMode == UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit) {
        CGFloat scale = MIN(ratioX, ratioY);

        targetRect.origin.x *= scale;
        targetRect.origin.y *= scale;

        targetRect.origin.x += (self.frame.size.width - sourceSize.width * scale) / 2.0f;
        targetRect.origin.y += (self.frame.size.height - sourceSize.height * scale) / 2.0f;

        targetRect.size.width *= scale;
        targetRect.size.height *= scale;
    }
    else if(self.contentMode == UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill) {
        CGFloat scale = MAX(ratioX, ratioY);

        targetRect.origin.x *= scale;
        targetRect.origin.y *= scale;

        targetRect.origin.x += (self.frame.size.width - sourceSize.width * scale) / 2.0f;
        targetRect.origin.y += (self.frame.size.height - sourceSize.height * scale) / 2.0f;

        targetRect.size.width *= scale;
        targetRect.size.height *= scale;
    }

    return targetRect;
}
```

When it's refactored and optimized, I'll publish it on github and post the link down here.
Maybe even that snippet could be helpful for someone.

Comment: I did today, see my other post. I hope you can make use of it!

Answer (score 1):

Nope, there is no built-in, public, or elegant way to do it.

You need to reverse engineer the functions for the content modes you need yourself.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do it for UIViewContentModeScaleToFill, UIViewContentModeAspectFit and UIViewContentModeAspectFill. That should be enough.

Comment: @nubbel - When done please make it public on github or in some other way, so that the next person do not have to jump through the same hoops.

Answer (score -1):

Why cant you just rescale the coordinates:

X(UIImageView) = (X(Image)/1024)*300

and

Y(UIImageView) = (Y(Image)/768)*300

Comment: That is good for UIViewContentModeScaleToFill, but for other contentModes?

Comment: doesn't work for UIContentModeScaleToFit since margin will appear and the image will be centered in the uiimageview