# Pixels to points on iPhone screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, drawing, pixel

I'm using an online OCR service that gives me each recognized word and its top/left point, width and height in pixels.

I'm having a hard time to convert them to points and draw a rectangle around the recognized words, because (I think) besides the conversion from pixels to points itself, the imageView that contains the image (and on which I want to draw the rectangles) has a "scale aspect fit" content mode.

This is how I get the image and send it to the web service:

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

[self.cameraView captureImageWithCompletionHander:^(id image)
 {
     self.cameraView.enableTorch = NO;
     self.captureImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
     self.captureImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.7];
     self.captureImageView.frame = CGRectOffset(weakSelf.view.bounds, 0, -weakSelf.view.bounds.size.height);
     self.captureImageView.alpha = 1.0;
     self.captureImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
     self.captureImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
     [self.cameraView addSubview:self.captureImageView];
     NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
     NSURL *urlSave = [[self getDocumentsPathURL] URLByAppendingPathComponent:k_IMAGE_NAME];
     [imageData writeToFile:urlSave.path atomically:NO];
     OCRController *ocrController = [OCRController sharedInstance];
     [ocrController callOCRSpace:(UIImage*)image
                      completion:^(NSArray *responseObject) {
                          [ProgressHUD dismiss];
                          NSLog(@"Results: %@", responseObject);
                          dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                              [self drawRectangleOnImage:self.scannedImage rect:responseObject];
                          });
                      } error:^(NSError *error) {
                          [ProgressHUD dismiss];
                          NSLog(@"Error OCR: %@", error.localizedDescription);
                      }];
```

And this is the method that draws the rectangles (I'm trying with just the first one for now):

```
- (void)drawRectangles:(NSArray*)objects {
    Words *firstObj = objects[0];
    NSLog(@"Word: %@", firstObj.wordText);
    UIView *rectView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake([firstObj.left floatValue] / 4, [firstObj.top floatValue] / 4, [firstObj.width floatValue] / 4, [firstObj.height floatValue] / 4)];
    rectView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    rectView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
    NSLog(@"Rect.:\nTop: %.2f - Left: %.2f\nWidth: %.2f - Height: %.2f", [firstObj.top floatValue] / 4, [firstObj.left floatValue] / 4, [firstObj.width floatValue] / 4, [firstObj.height floatValue] / 4);
    [self.captureImageView addSubview:rectView];
}
```

And this is the result for the first detected word "Gracias" on the top-left of the image:

[image: example]

**Edit** after Prashant Tukadiya's answer:

```
- (void)drawRectangles:(NSArray*)objects {
    Words *firstObj = objects[0];
    CGPoint imagePoints = CGPointMake([firstObj.left doubleValue], [firstObj.top doubleValue]);
    float percentX = imagePoints.x / self.scannedImage.size.width;
    float percentY = imagePoints.y / self.scannedImage.size.height;
    CGPoint imageViewPoints = CGPointMake(self.captureImageView.frame.size.width * percentX, self.captureImageView.frame.size.height * percentY);

    UIView *rectView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(imageViewPoints.x, imageViewPoints.y, [firstObj.width floatValue], [firstObj.height floatValue])];
    rectView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
    rectView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
    [self.captureImageView addSubview:rectView];
}
```

I've also added the category UIImageView+GeometryConversion from the linked answer, but I really don't know how to use it.

I'm pretty new to all this coordinates thing and I'm really lost.

This is the result so far, looks like the I've got the X right, at least:

[image]

**Second Edit**: I'm very near

So, I've found another example and created a new method:

```
-(void)drawRectangleOnImage:(UIImage *)img rect:(NSArray *)objects {
    CGSize imgSize = img.size;
    CGFloat scale = 0;
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imgSize, NO, scale);
    [img drawAtPoint:CGPointZero];

    for (Words *item in objects) {
        CGRect rect = [self.captureImageView convertRect:CGRectMake([item.left doubleValue], [item.top doubleValue], [item.width floatValue], [item.height floatValue]) toView:self.captureImageView];
        [[UIColor greenColor] setFill];
        UIRectFill(rect);
        NSLog(@"Palabra: %@\nRect: %@\n\n", item.wordText, NSStringFromCGRect(rect));
    }

    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    self.captureImageView.image = newImage;
}
```

This time I've been able to draw a rectangle on each recognized word. The problems now are:

1. draw an empty rectangle (I haven't been able to do it yet and, yes, I feel stupid)
2. give the user the possibility to zoom the image, touch a word on the image and only then, draw the rectangle around that word

This is my last result:

[image]

Comment: which points you are getting according to image ?

Comment: Top: 163.75 - Left: 134.50
Width: 86.25 - Height: 26.25

Comment: Try to convert that point according to uiimageView. you are doing is wrong `[firstObj.left floatValue] / 4,`  you need reverse what he did here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17200191/converting-uiimageview-touch-coordinates-to-uiimage-coordinates/17200285#17200285

Comment: I am not sure but         `CGRect rect = [self.captureImageView convertRect:CGRectMake([item.left doubleValue], [item.top doubleValue], [item.width floatValue], [item.height floatValue]) toView:self.captureImageView];` it has no use means it will return same coordinates whichever passed. and you can use StrokeColor to just provide a border instead of fill

Comment: For **give the user the possibility to zoom the image, touch a word on the image and only then, draw the rectangle around that word** you can use self.zoomScale of your scrollview's zoomScale property. you need to either divide you points with zoom scale or multiply your points with zoom scale according to user action. Hope that can help you

Comment: I'll give it a try. I hope to make it. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is static divide every points with 4 like `[firstObj.left floatValue] / 4`

There is no inbuilt method that allows to conversion from `UIImage` to `UIImageView` and vise-versa

So as i mentioned in comment you need to do is

```
CGPoint imagePoints =  ..whatever your points you are getting 

float percentX = imagePoints.x / yourImage.size.width;
float percentY = imagePoints.y / yourImage.size.height;

CGPoint imageViewPoints = CGPointMake(imageView.frame.size.width * percentX, imageView.frame.size.height * percentY);
```

Here you will get  imageViewPoints so you can add your subview with that point. One more thing is you need to handle aspect ratio too.  see this post [Convert points from image to UIImageView points, contentMode-aware](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7216663/convert-points-from-image-to-uiimageview-points-contentmode-aware/10212280#10212280) for that.

Hope it is helpful

Comment: I've edited my question with the updated results. Thanks for helping.

Comment: @Aleph72 Why you are getting x correct because image is landscape (see black part on top). if you try portrait images then you will get Y correct position. so you need to calculate that part also

Comment: The image is not landscape. The black part is for an offset set to the imageView's frame (look at  the first part of the code).

Comment: Yes just print image size you will see that image width is greater than height so its aspect ratio is landscape

Comment: Image dimensions: 3024.00 x 4032.00